# How to query Child elements on MongoDB

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

it's quite looklike with [how to query child objects in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762947/how-to-query-child-objects-in-mongodb)

I Have:

[image]

Pais (Country) with its children (ufds(27) on total), I'm making a Ruby seed.rb file to bulky insert from a file.

the mapping files are:

```
class Pais
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :nome, :type => String
  field :sigla, :type => String

  embeds_many :ufds
  validates_uniqueness_of :sigla
end

class Ufd
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :codigo_ibge, :type => String
  field :sigla, :type => String
  field :nome, :type => String

  embedded_in :pais, :inverse_of => :ufds
  embeds_many :cidades

  validates_uniqueness_of :codigo_ibge, :sigla
end

class Cidade
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :codigo_ibge, :type => String
  field :nome, :type => String

  embedded_in :ufd, :inverse_of => :cidades
  validates_uniqueness_of :codigo_ibge
end
```

So when importing, I do beside other things the following:

```
pais_base = Pais.create!(:nome => "Brasil", :sigla => "BR")

File.open(caminho + 'estados.txt').each_with_index do |linha, index|
  sigla, nome, ibge = linha.chomp.split("|")
  pais_base.ufds << Ufd.new(:sigla => sigla, :nome => nome, :codigo_ibge => ibge )
end
```

which creates correctly the PAIS and its UFDS children, but now to create a children of UFDS, I load another file and try to find a UFDS with id (codigo_ibge), but always returns null

```
File.open(caminho + 'cidades.txt').each_with_index do |linha, index|
  ufd, ibge, nome = linha.chomp.split("|")
  uf = pais_base.ufds.find(:first, :conditions => {:codigo_ibge => ufd.to_s }) <<<<< NIL
  uf.cidades << Cidade.new(:codigo_ibge => ibge.to_s, :nome => nome)
end
```

How should I do that? I've run out of ideas :/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of mongoid are you using?

I think your best bet is to use where

This would make your query

```
  uf = pais_base.ufds.where(:codigo_ibge => ufd.to_s }.first
```

find is only really used when you are looking up an id.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew about that. Do you have more reading links about it?

Comment: Your best bet is the mongoid docs, and reading the code if that doesn't help