# Mongodb query array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to get all documents that match an array of objects or an object with many fields.

**Example 1 (array of objects)**
If the document match the country_code than he must have one of postal_codes too

```
var locations = [
  {
    country_code : 'IT',
    postal_codes : [21052, 21053, 21054, 21055]
  },
  {
    country_code : 'GER',
    postal_codes : [41052, 41053, 41054, 41055]
  }
]
```

**Example 2 (object with fields)**
If the document match the key than it must have one of the values of that key

```
var location = {
  'IT' : [21052, 21053, 21054, 21055],
  'GER' : [41052, 41053, 41054, 41055]
}
```

I like the first type of document to match(array of objects) but how can i use to get all documents that match?

The documents to find have this structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("587f6f57ed6b9df409db7370"),
  "description" : "Test description",
  "address" : {
      "postal_code" : "21052",
      "country_code" : "IT"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$in` to find such collections.

```
db.collection_name.find(
                     { address.postal_code: { $in: [your values] } },
                   )
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762947/how-to-query-child-objects-in-mongodb) for querying child objects. 
Check this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) for mongoDB `$in`

Comment: You can add multiple conditions as required to achieve the results.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `$or` operator. This will help you limit the combinations of `country_code` and `postal_code`.

Your query should look something like this.

```
db.locations.find({
    $or: [{
        "country_code": "IT",
        "postal_code": {
            $in: [21052, 21053, 21054, 21055]
        }
    }, {
        "country_code": "GER",
        "postal_code": {
            $in: [41052, 41053, 41054, 41055]
        }
    }]
})
```